# What are the best approaches to remove similar but not equal lines from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Suppose I have a CSV file like this:

```
GENE,01,07,Et fecit Deus expansionem: et divisit aquas quae erant sub,,,,
GENE,01,07,"expansione, ab a",,,,
GENE,01,07,"expansione, ab aquis quae erant super expansionem. Et fuit ita.",,,,
GENE,01,08,"Vocavitque Deus expansionem, Caelum. Et fuit vespera, et fuit mane",,,,
GENE,01,08,dies secundus.,,,,
```

Line 2 is an error where the text was incorrectly truncated. The file has around 53K lines. For lines where the first three columns are equal and the first *n* characters of column four are equal, I'd like to keep the line where len(column4) is greater.

I've been doing the pre-processing in Python 3, but open to other approaches.

Comment: *The file has around 53K lines.* what is its size in megabytes? Would it fit into RAM of your machine?

Comment: What did you try already? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: 3.5MB, so yes, it would fit in memory

Comment: Show what code you have that produced the error.

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem, you should mark it as resolved by clicking the tick mark ( _or upvote_ ). [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Let us try this using `groupby.max()` and take the row with maximum length in `col4` after grouping by first 3 columns and first 4 characters of `col4`

```
df1 = df.assign(length=(df["col4"].str.len()))\
        .groupby(['col1','col2','col3',df.col4.str[:4]],as_index=False)\
        .max().drop('length',axis=1)
```

*I have used first 4 characters here. Change accordingly in str[:4]*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C0, C1, C2 and C3 are your columns names :

```
# get first n chars from C3 after checking for s type
df['text_n'] = df['C3'].apply(lambda s : s[:n] if s is not None and type(s) == str else '')
df['len_text'] = df['C3'].apply(lambda s : len(s) if s is not None and type(s) == str else 0)
df2 = df.groupBy(['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'text_n', 'len_text']).count()
# keep only the first record with most text length
df_output = df2.sort_values(by = ['len_text'], ascending = False).drop_duplicates(['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'text_n'])
```

There must be a cleaner way, I think about window functions instead of my useless count to go from a groupby df to a pandas df, but this one should do the job.